# getting error Object(...) is not a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I have created a custom component and compile with `webpack` in umd format .it create a bundle file in `dist` folder .I want to use that component in my another project without publishing. I copied that file in my project .but getting error this

**Object(...) is not a function**

I am using like this

```
import "./styles.css";
import X from "./test";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <X />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I copied my webpack complied bundle in `test.js` file and try to include that component

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-dust-bmupm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The relevant code should be posted **here**, not on some external site.

Comment: compiled code is big file that why I didn't paste

Comment: The error is *probably* a missing semicolon somewhere.